# I need to use a jQuery function to check the range of numbers and to see if it's validated and it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I have just begun to learn how to use jQuery I need to validate an input field and test the range of numbers entered. I have written what I believe would be the correct way to do it but it doesn't work, in fact if you do enter a number between the range nothing occurs in the game. I would also like to have the input box turn "red" if the number entered isn't in the range, as well as put the output message I have included in my code if it doesn't fit.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dice.css">
    <title>Dice Game</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#guess').focus();
            $('#roll').click(function () {});

            $("#guess").validate({
                rules: {
                    guess: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [2, 12]
                    }
                }, //end of rules

                message: {

                    guess: {
                        required: "Please enter a    number.",
                        range: "You must enter a    number between 2 and 12."
                    }
                }
            }); //end of validate()

            var count = 3;

            function startover() {
                count = 3;
                alert("Make a guess and click the Roll button.");
            }

            function roll(guess) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    alert("Click the Play Again button.");
                    return;
                }

                var die1 = Math.floor(1 + 6 * Math.random());
                var die2 = Math.floor(1 + 6 * Math.random());

                var sum = die1 + die2;

                if (guess == sum) {
                    alert("You rolled a " + die1 + " and a " + die2 +
                        " which adds up to " + sum + ".  Your guess is " +
                        guess + ".  Congratulations, you win!");
                    count = 0;
                } else {
                    --count;
                    if (count == 0) {
                        alert("You rolled a " + die1 + " and a " + die2 +
                            " which adds up to " + sum + ".  Your guess is " +
                            guess + ".  You have no rolls left.  " +
                            "Sorry... the computer won.");
                    } else {
                        alert("You rolled a " + die1 + " and a " + die2 +
                            " which adds up to " + sum + ".  Your guess is " +
                            guess + ".  You have " + count + " rolls left.  " +
                            "Click Roll to try again.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }); // end ready    </script>
    <form id="game">
        <h1>Welcome to the dice game!</h1>
        <p>Here's how it works! If you roll two dice and add up the values, you will get a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 12.</p>
        <p>Enter a number between 2 and 12:
            <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess" min="2" max="12" />
            <br>The computer will roll the dice for you up to three times. If the dice match your guess, you win!</p>
        <input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="roll(guess.value);" />
        <input type="button" value="Play Again" onclick="startover();" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you link the validation library you are using with jQuery?

Comment: I was unaware I needed to have a validation library attached to my code. Any suggestions on what one to use? I am a beginner when it comes to coding.

Comment: I added the following to my code for validation: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are these problems with your code:

1. javascript functions for button event handler should NOT be placed inside $(document).ready();
2. jQuery validate plugin should be run on your form element ($("#game").validate), NOT on your input text element ($("#guess").validate).
3. In order for invalid input to be highlighted, you need to add 'error' and 'valid' css styles.
4. In order to stop the game from proceeding, you can disable submit buttons when form validation fails, using:

   `onkeyup: function (element, event ) {
     if(!$("#game").valid()) {
       $(":button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     } else {
       $(":button").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
     }
   }`

Please see [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/CbWgEsujLOnFVnJT0pdB/) with working code.

Note: I haven't looked at your game logic, and haven't modified it, I have fixed the validation part.

Answer (score 0):

`validate` is not a method in the jQuery core API and you are not linking to any other jQuery plugins.  Looks like you are missing a SCRIPT tag for your validation plugin

Comment: I added this link for my validation: <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript. There's no need to specifically use jQuery for this.
With JavaScript, all you need to do is handle the 'roll' button click event:

```
 var btnButton = document.getElementById('roll');    
btnButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var txtValue = document.getElementById('guess').value;
    if (txtValue.length > 0) {
        if (!isNaN(+txtValue)) {
            if (txtValue > 2 && txtValue < 12) {
                document.getElementById('spanValidationMsg').className = "hide";
                //WRITE YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE
                //WRITE YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE
                }
            else {
                document.getElementById('spanValidationMsg').innerHTML = "You must enter a number between 2 and 12.";
                }
            }
        }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('spanValidationMsg').innerHTML = "Please enter a number";
        document.getElementById('spanValidationMsg').className = "show";
     }
});
```

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jL26k/2/

EDIT: There was a small error. Check the link now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it still allows you to guess numbers outside of the range and the game continues on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector is wrong, you should be selecting the form element not the guess element.

e.g. it should be `$('#game').validate({` ...

To get the form inputs to change color read the documentation here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#errorclass